# App Store Connect: ITMS-90492: Invalid WatchKit Support

Tags: swift, watchos

I tried updating a stand alone WatchOS app to the App Store and got this message from iTunes after uploading it:

`ITMS-90492: Invalid WatchKit Support - The file WK doesn’t have the correct code signature. Make sure you’re using the correct signature, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it. Don’t just modify the code signature of WK.`

I have uploaded previous version without a problem, so I think it might have something to do with using `WKInterfaceDevice().play(.click)` in my code which is new to the version uploaded, but I  am not entirely sure, has anyone ran into a similar problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: Did you find answer for this..? I have the same email for seemingly correct build.

Comment: @AleksandarVacić see the answer below. Greetings from Belgrade ;)

Answer (score 0):

This appears if you have XCode beta installed on your Mac. It doesn't have to run just its simple presence results in this artefact.